# How do I add a media image field?

Tags: 8, media

I have installed these modules:

- [Media Entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/media_entity)
- [Media Entity Image](https://www.drupal.org/project/media_entity_image)
- [Entity Browser](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_browser)

When I try to add an image field, I have no widget for Media like there was in Drupal 7.
I also tried to add a reference to a media, but it doesn't seem to work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you got can do what you want, but it requires configuration and without a UI it's quite hard.

You might want to try adding the [file browser](https://www.drupal.org/project/file_browser) module, which uses Dropszonejs to create a nice file browser widget. I have tested it out and it seemed to work just fine, but it wasn't quite mature enough for what we wanted to do at the time.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work just fine. Can you go on your experience with file browser vs media ?

Answer (score -1):

You have to add new references field (other) and select media. Now you can select media or create per Entity browser :)